# Flutter change checkbox tick icon size

Tags: flutter, checkbox, icons, size, scale

Is it possible to change the tick size of checkbox ? i tried wrapping the `CheckBox` with `Transform.scale` with `scale: 2.0` but it makes the whole `CheckBox` button bigger.

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you will try asset image instead of icon for check box.